# Two additional Saturn V flights planned in 1967 - but for what?

Tags: apollo-program, history, saturn-v

Per [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18953/when-was-the-second-production-run-of-the-saturn-v-cancelled), there was no "cancelled" second run of Saturn Vs: only the first fifteen were ordered, and no second batch was ordered and then later cancelled. This had always been my understanding as well.

However, it seems that some small steps were made towards procuring at least two more in addition to the original contract, SA-516 and SA-517.

From *Saturn: an illustrated chronology*, [part 8, Jan-Dec 1967](https://history.nasa.gov/MHR-5/part-8.htm):

> MSFC announced on July 26 [1967] that NASA had awarded a $2.275 million contract to the Boeing Company for procurement of long-lead-time materials for two additional Saturn V flight boosters. The CPFF contract was the first Saturn V procurement in support of NASA's Apollo Applications Program. Boeing, prime contractor for the 7.5 million-pound-thrust first stage (S-IC) of the Saturn V launch vehicle, was manufacturing 12 stages at MAF, for the Apollo manned lunar exploration program. Boeing would begin acquiring such items as propellant ducts, liquid oxygen tunnels, and fuel tank components for the 16th and 17th stages. The contract would expire on January 1, 1968.

This approach of paying for a few long-lead items in advance of formally approving the contract for the full batch seems to have been normal; elsewhere in the chronology there is mention of it having been done for additional Saturn IBs (Dec 1966), and for the last five S-II stages (Sep 1967).

However, a few months later:

> Also on October 4 [1967] NASA informed the Boeing Company that it was terminating procurement of 10 S-IC stages, S-IC-16 through S-IC-25. Boeing had submitted a proposal on July 3 and an adjusted proposal on September 20 covering the necessary supplies and services for fabrication and delivery of the stages.

So it seems that for a short period in mid-late 1967, there was a belief that procurement of at least two additional Saturn Vs would be funded shortly (in the 1968 budget?) - to the extent that NASA was willing to put money down to keep the option open - and with a sense that they were specifically earmarked for "Apollo Applications". By October, this was cancelled, along with any suggestion of a full batch of ten boosters.

So what were these two boosters intended *for*? As far as I can work out, the decision to go for a Saturn V launched Skylab did not come until 1969, and at that point it was given a repurposed lunar Saturn V. Was it speculative on the grounds that AAP would probably require Saturn Vs for *something*? Were they for Voyager Mars? Something else?

Comment: Apollo 20 and ???